# Parent have list of child or Child have a parent reference

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I am designing a database. Am using hibernate. I have Two type of class hierarchy

Case 1:

```
class Parent{
private Long id
private String name;
}

class Child{
private Parent parentId;
private String name;
}
```

Case 2:

```
class Parent{
    private Long id
    private String name;
    private List<Child> childs;
    }

class Child{
private String name;
}
```

My question is which is better approach to do?

Comment: I would prefer Approach 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to handle and access the Parent Child Relationship.

Case 1 is good if you only want to access Parent from Child only and Child is the owner of the Parent.

Case 2 is good if you want to access the List of Children from Parent but individual Child doesn't have reference to Parent. This time Parent becomes the owner of the Child and you can control Cascading like if you delete a Parent you can delete all Children associated with it.

I personally like a Case 3 which is a Hybrid of both.

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate you can map these associations with collections and annotations like `@OneToMany` etc., exactly as your second example shows.

I recommend [this StackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511237/how-to-use-hibernate-annotations-manytoone-and-onetomany-for-associations) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

Why not both of them? Hibernate manages it very good:

```
class Parent {

    private Long id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> children;

}

class Child {

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

}
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional for more details.